# Is there easy way to extend space in partition?

Tags: dual-boot, partitioning, 20.04, windows, storage

Is there an easy way to resize partition?

I have a dual boot laptop with windows and Ubuntu at the beginning I didn't think I will use Linux this often, so I have given 50GB only, but with time I even stopped using Windows :D

Now I would like to take some free space which windows don't use and extend the ubuntu OS storage. I am very new to Linux so I would like sth with UI or a simple way to do, does anyone know?

I've tried
gparted but didn't work
I've tried Easeus but it requires premium for EXT4

DONE

ppl in the comments answered my question, if anyone looking for answer

Comment: Need to do it from a live USB.  It is easier and safer for data if you are lucky and have free space to the right of the partition.  Back up all important data before doing.  Should do Windows partitions with Windows tools and Linux partitions with Linux tools for best results.

Comment: As @crip659 says the key to this is a live environment. That means boot what ever you used to install Ubuntu, choose “try” rather than install and use GParted from there. Use Windows tools for the Windows partitions first